# c# Remove rows from csv

Tags: c#, .net, linq, csv

I have two csv files. In the first file i have a list of users, and in the second file i have a list of duplicate users. Im trying to remove the rows in the first file that are equal to the second file.

Heres the code i have so far:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path3);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path2);

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string user = sr.ReadLine();

            if (line != user) 
            {
                sw.WriteLine(line);

            }
```

File 1 example:

```
Modify,ABAMA3C,Allpay - Free State - HO,09072701

Modify,ABCG327,Processing Centre,09085980
```

File 2 Example:

```
Modify,ABAA323,Group HR Credit Risk & Finance

Modify,ABAB959,Channel Sales & Service,09071036
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide example file format in your post...

Comment: Your code looks incomplete, you need to close your foreach loop and close your StreamWriter/Reader

Comment: Looks like homework, too. Flagged as so, feel free to change if you object to it.

Comment: Why don't you split both csv files into a List<String> where each element is a line from your csv file, and then do a foreach on the first csv list and check if the line is contained in the second list? Sort of like:
foreach(string elem in List){ if(ListTwo.Contains(elem)){ //remove the line from the list here}}
In the end just overwrite your file with the remaining results.

Comment: i do flush and close the the stream writer, later in the code. this is part of a bigger source, so i just took out a snippet.

Comment: where is the duplication, you mean duplication per token or per line ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you'd have to do is change the following file paths in the code below and you will get a file back (file one) without the duplicate users from file 2. This code was written with the idea in mind that you want something that is easy to understand. Sure there are other more elegant solutions, but I wanted to make it as basic as possible for you:

**(Paste this in the main method of your program)**

```
        string line;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\J\Desktop\texts\First.txt");

        StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\J\Desktop\texts\Second.txt");

        List<String> fileOne = new List<string>();
        List<String> fileTwo = new List<string>();

        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            if(line != "")
            {
                fileOne.Add(line);
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
        while (sr2.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            line = sr2.ReadLine();
            if (line != "")
            {
                fileTwo.Add(line);
            }
        }
        sr2.Close();
        var t = fileOne.Except(fileTwo);

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\justin\Desktop\texts\First.txt");

        foreach(var z in t)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(z);
        }
        sw.Flush();
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is not homework, but a production thing, and you can install assemblies, you'll save 3 hours of your life if you swallow your pride and use a piece of the VB library:

There are many exceptions (CR/LF between commas=legal in quotes; different types of quotes; etc.) This will handle anything excel will export/import.

Sample code to load a 'Person' class pulled from a program I used it in:

```
    Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(CSVPath)

        Reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        Reader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        Reader.TrimWhiteSpace = True
        Reader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

        While Not Reader.EndOfData
            Try
                Dim st2 As New List(Of String)
                st2.addrange(Reader.ReadFields())
                If iCount > 0 Then ' ignore first row = field names
                    Dim p As New Person
                    p.CSVLine = st2
                    p.FirstName = st2(1).Trim
                    If st2.Count > 2 Then
                        p.MiddleName = st2(2).Trim
                    Else
                        p.MiddleName = ""
                    End If
                    p.LastNameSuffix = st2(0).Trim
                    If st2.Count >= 5 Then
                        p.TestCase = st2(5).Trim
                    End If
                    If st2(3) > "" Then
                        p.AccountNumbersFromCase.Add(st2(3))
                    End If
                    While p.CSVLine.Count < 15
                        p.CSVLine.Add("")
                    End While
                    cases.Add(p)
                End If
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & " is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
            iCount += 1
        End While
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

this to close the streams properly:

```
using(var sw = new StreamWriter(path3))
using(var sr = new StreamReader(path2))
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string user = sr.ReadLine();

        if (line != user)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

for help on the real logic of removal or compare, answer the comment of El Ronnoco above...

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the streams or utilize using clause

```
sw.Close();

using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\test3.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fullList = "TextFile1.txt".ReadAsLines();
        var removeThese = "TextFile2.txt".ReadAsLines();

        //Change this line if you need to change the filter results.
        //Note: this assume you are wanting to remove results from the first 
        //      list when the entire record matches.  If you want to match on 
        //      only part of the list you will need to split/parse the records 
        //      and then filter your results.
        var cleanedList = fullList.Except(removeThese);

        cleanedList.WriteAsLinesTo("result.txt");
    }
}
public static class Tools
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadAsLines(this string filename)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                yield return reader.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void WriteAsLinesTo(this IEnumerable<string> lines, string filename)
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename) { AutoFlush = true, })
            foreach (var line in lines)
                writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using(var sw = new StreamWriter(path3))
using(var sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string []arrRemove = File.ReadAllLines(path2);
    HashSet<string> listRemove = new HashSet<string>(arrRemove.Count);
    foreach(string s in arrRemove)
    {
        string []sa = s.Split(',');
        if( sa.Count < 2 ) continue;
        listRemove.Add(sa[1].toUpperCase());
    }

    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    while( line != null )
    {
        string []sa = line.Split(',');
        if( sa.Count < 2 )
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        else if( !listRemove.contains(sa[1].toUpperCase()) )
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```